# Null Output while fetching data from mysql with php and showing json output

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

Hello guys I am new to PHP and working with **json array** output with prepare statement but getting null output. What is wrong with this code and why I am getting null output and how to fix that. init.php fil provides the connection of MySQL database.

```
<?php
    require "init.php";
    $post_id = $_POST["pid"];

    if($post_id == ""){

        echo "Empty";

    }else{

        $result = $con->prepare("SELECT * from Posts
                INNER JOIN Users 
                ON Posts.Uid = Users.Uid 
                WHERE Posts.Pid= ? AND Posts.Active = 0)");
```

//problem is ")" in the query

```
        $result->bind_param("i", $post_id);
        $result->execute();

        $rows= array();
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $rows[] = array('post_id'=>$row['Pid'],'user_id'=>$row['Uid'],'post_cat'=>$row['Post_Category'],
                            'user_name'=>$row['User_Name'],'user_profile'=> $row['User_Image'],'post_time'=>$row['Post_Time'],
                            'post_title'=>utf8_encode($row['Post_Title']),'post_desc'=>$row['Post_Desc'],
                            'post_exp'=>$row['Post_Expiry'],'img_link'=>$row['Post_Image'],
                            'post_url'=>$row['Post_Url'],'post_type'=>$row['Post_Type']);
        }
        if (json_encode($rows) == '[]'  || json_encode($rows) == null) {
            echo "No_Post";
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array("post"=>$rows));
        }
        $result->close();

    }
?>
```

I am also trying to make PHP code secure but don't know how ?.And what problem can be arise in this code. How could I make this Secure. Thanks in Advance.

**Update**

```
<?php
    require "init.php";

    $post_id = $_POST["pid"];

        $result = mysqli_query($con,""SELECT * from Posts
                INNER JOIN Users 
                ON Posts.Uid = Users.Uid 
                WHERE Posts.Pid= ? AND Posts.Active = 0");

    $rows= array();
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rows[] = array('post_id'=>$row['Pid'],'user_id'=>$row['Uid'],'post_cat'=>$row['Post_Category'],
            'user_name'=>$row['User_Name'],'user_profile'=> $row['User_Image'],'post_time'=>$row['Post_Time'],
            'post_title'=>utf8_encode($row['Post_Title']),'post_desc'=>$row['Post_Desc'],
            'post_exp'=>$row['Post_Expiry'],'img_link'=>$row['Post_Image'],
            'post_url'=>$row['Post_Url'],'post_type'=>$row['Post_Type']);

    }
    if (json_encode($rows) == '[]'  || json_encode($rows) == null) {
        echo "No_Post";
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array("post"=>$rows));
    }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This code giving correct output but SQL Injection can be easily implemented in this updated code. How to stop SQL Injection in updated code ?

Comment: What does `$rows` contain after the loop: `var_dump($rows);`? And if your script is supposed to return json, you should also return json when there are errors or the result set is empty. Otherwise it will be a lot harder to process on the receiving end.

Comment: var_dump what is that

Comment: Ummmmm, okay, never mind...

Comment: and this " $post_id = $_POST["pid"];" where are you getting the "pid" in the post variable?

Comment: I am using postman tool to post data

Comment: ok **jeroen** I'll implement that soon

Comment: Found problem that was in the query ")" thank you guys for helping